# Replace string with random text - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `table1` with 1 column - `edi_value` which is of type `CLOB`.

These are the entries:

```
seq  edi_message
1    ISA*00*          *00*          *08*9254110060     *ZZ*123456789      *041216*0805*U*00501*000095071*0*P*>~
    GS*AG*5137624388*123456789*20041216*0805*95071*X*005010~
    ST*824*021390001*005010X186A1~

2    ISA*00*          *00*          *08*56789876678     *ZZ*123456789      *041216*0805*U*00501*000095071*0*P*>~
    GS*AG*5137624388*123456789*20041216*0805*95071*X*005010~
    ST*824*021390001*005010X186A1~
```

> Please note - there can be varying number of lines, from 3 to 500.

What I'm looking for is the following conditions:

- Ignore text before first * in each line, for every line, before the first *, it should not change. For ex. GS, ST should not change. ONLY after the first * should randomize
- Replace numbers [0-9] with random numbers, for ex. if 0 is replaced with 1, then it should be 1 througout.
- Replace text [A-Za-z] with random text, for ex. if A is replaced with W, then it should be replaced with W throughout
- Leave special characters as is

> One character/number should ONLY map to one random character/number

Output can be:

```
seq  edi_message
1    ISA*11*          *11*          *13*4030111101     *QQ*102030234      *101010*1313*U*11311*111143121*1*V*>~
    GS*WE*3122000233*102030234*01101010*1313*43121*X*113111~
    ST*300*101241111*113111X130A1~

2    ISA*11*          *11*          *13*30234320023     *QQ*102030234      *101010*1313*U*11311*111143121*1*V*>~
    GS*WE*3122000233*102030234*01101010*1313*43121*X*113111~
    ST*300*101241111*113111X130W1~
```

How can this be achieved in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`translate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TRANSLATE.html#GUID-80F85ACB-092C-4CC7-91F6-B3A585E3A690) with a helper function for generating random strings (though @LukStorms has a [much neater SQL solution for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55316374/6854914) using `LISTAGG`), along with a method to tokenise and then re-concatenate the values into lines (I use a pure SQL method here for demonstration):

> ```
> create or replace function f(p_low integer, p_high integer) 
>     return varchar as
>   r varchar(2000) := '';
>   x integer;
> begin
>   for i in p_low..p_high loop
>     x := dbms_random.value(0,length(r)+1);
>     r := substr(r,1,x)||chr(i)||substr(r,x+1);
>   end loop;
>   return r;
> end;
> /
> ```

> ```
> select * from table1;
> ```
>
> ```
> | EDI_VALUE                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | ISA*00*          *00*          *08*9254110060     *ZZ*123456789      *041216*0805*U*00501*000095071*0*P*>~<br>    GS*AG*5137624388*123456789*20041216*0805*95071*X*005010~<br>    ST*824*021390001*005010X186A1~ |
> | ISA*00*          *00*          *08*56789876678     *ZZ*123456789      *041216*0805*U*00501*000095071*0*P*>~<br>    GS*AG*5137624388*123456789*20041216*0805*95071*X*005010~<br>    ST*824*021390001*005010X186A  |
> ```

> ```
> with t as (select f(48,57)||f(65,90) translate_chars from dual)
> select (select new_value
>         from (select substr(sys_connect_by_path(r_line,'
> '),2) new_value, connect_by_isleaf isleaf
>               from (select lvl
>                          , substr(line,1,instr(line,'*')-1)||
>                              translate(substr(line,instr(line,'*'))
>                                       ,'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>                                       ,(select translate_chars from t)) r_line
>                     from (select level lvl
>                                , regexp_substr(edi_value,'^.*$',1,level,'m') line
>                           from (select table1.edi_value from dual)
>                           connect by level <= regexp_count(edi_value,'^.*$',1,'m')))
>               start with lvl=1 connect by lvl=(prior lvl)+1)
>         where isleaf=1)
> from table1;
> ```
>
> ```
> | (SELECTNEW_VALUEFROM(SELECTSUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(R_LINE,''),2)NEW_VALUE,CONNECT_BY_ISLEAFISLEAFFROM(SELECTLVL,SUBSTR(LINE,1,INSTR(LINE,'*')-1)||TRANSLATE(SUBSTR(LINE,INSTR(LINE,'*')),'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',(SELECTTRANSLATE_CHARSFR |
> | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | ISA*66*          *66*          *67*1935006626     *VV*098532471      *650902*6763*K*66360*666613640*6*P*>~<br>    GS*GZ*3084295877*098532471*96650902*6763*13640*I*663606~<br>    ST*795*690816660*663606I072G0~                                            |
> | ISA*66*          *66*          *67*32471742247     *VV*098532471      *650902*6763*K*66360*666613640*6*P*>~<br>    GS*GZ*3084295877*098532471*96650902*6763*13640*I*663606~<br>    ST*795*690816660*663606I072G                                             |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d42b5b7f252fc21b0dbf87814c2c0666)*

Comment: This works great! If I want to change it so that it does not change values for TWO (2) * for each change, which code should I change? For ex. ST*824* should remain as is, and ONLY the next part getting changed?

Comment: [`instr`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm) has two optional parameters, `position` and `occurrence` for that sort of thing so that's a minor tweak: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=67ae6abf39a8466651974982225861d2

Comment: Are you on Skype?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE's with a CONNECT to generate the strings for the letters and numbers.

Then use the ordered and scrambled strings in the translate.

A [CROSS APPLY](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1#cross-apply-join) can be used to REGEX split the message into parts.
Then only translate those that start with a `*`.
And use LISTAGG to glue the parts back together.

```
WITH 
NUMS as
(
  select 
  LISTAGG(n, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY n) as n_from,
  LISTAGG(n, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) as n_to
  from (select level-1 n from dual connect by level <= 10) 
),
LETTERS as
(
  select 
  LISTAGG(c, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c) as c_from,
  LISTAGG(c, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) as c_to
  from (select chr(ascii('A')+level-1 ) c from dual connect by level <= 26) 
)
SELECT ca.scrambled as scrambled_message
FROM table1 t
CROSS JOIN NUMS
CROSS JOIN LETTERS
CROSS APPLY 
(
 SELECT LISTAGG(CASE WHEN part like '*%' then translate(part, n_from||c_from, n_to||c_to) else part end, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lvl) as scrambled
 FROM
 (
  SELECT 
  level AS lvl,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.edi_message,'[*]\S+|[^*]+',1,level,'m') AS part
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count(t.edi_message, '[*]\S+|[^*]+')+1
 ) parts
) ca;
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8f84879df5af711ba5b3133e3047083b)*

**Example output:**

```
SCRAMBLED_MESSAGE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ISA*99*          *99*          *92*3525999959     *PP*950525023      *959595*9292*A*99299*999932909*9*J*>~
    GS*WQ*2900555022*950525023*59959595*9292*32909*I*992999~
    ST*255*959039999*992999I925V9~
ISA*99*          *99*          *92*25023205502     *PP*950525023      *959595*9292*A*99299*999932909*9*J*>~
    GS*WQ*2900555022*950525023*59959595*9292*32909*I*992999~
    ST*255*959039999*992999I925W9~
```

Comment: really neat way of generating the translate strings. You can just concatenate them rather than nesting `translate`s can't you?

Comment: like this I mean: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=406720cbfa97333417f2478764079e83

Comment: Omg, you make a good point about concatinating them. (why didn't I see the obvious!) Thanks.

Comment: It changes line 2 and line 3 in the same row. I mean GS, ST should remain as is and not change.

Comment: Oh like that.  Not just the start of the varchar, but also after newlines in the string. Hmm, that's gonna be a tad harder to do.

Comment: @dang It's fixed now.  The regex pattern that's used is a bit more flexible than just using the new-lines for splitting the string.